# How do I assign data from a weather api object to individual html elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on building out my first JS weather app, using the Openweathermap API and vanilla javascript. I'm attempting to set it up such that it provides a basic 5 day forecast when a user enters their city into the search field. The API returns an object that contains an array, which contains 5 objects corresponding to each day (one such object included in the code below). I then want to use that data to set the appropriate information to display within the HTML (an example of one of the HTML cards is also provided below).

How do I iterate over this array to apply the correct pieces of data to their corresponding html elements? Specifically I need to grab the current temp, the date, the weather description, and the humidity and apply it to the respective html element.

One object from array of data

```
 [
  {
    "dt": 1614632400,
    "main": {
      "temp": 56.64,
      "feels_like": 48.09,
      "temp_min": 56.64,
      "temp_max": 56.95,
      "pressure": 1025,
      "sea_level": 1025,
      "grnd_level": 953,
      "humidity": 12,
      "temp_kf": -0.17
    },
    "weather": [
      {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01d"
      }
    ],
    "clouds": {
      "all": 1
    },
    "wind": {
      "speed": 4.36,
      "deg": 71
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "pop": 0,
    "sys": {
      "pod": "d"
    },
    "dt_txt": "2021-03-01 21:00:00"
  },
]
```

One HTML card

```
   <div class="forecast-card">
     <h2 class="date">Saturday</h2>
     <h2 class="current-temp">57</h2>
     <img src="./icons/unknown.png" alt="weather icons" class="icon">
     <p class="conditions">Clear Sky</p>
     <h3 class="high-temp">
      High
     </h3>
     <h3 class="low-temp">
      Low
     </h3>
     <p class="humidity">80%</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: @Dominik sorry, got a bit hasty posting. Edited the post to include my question.

Comment: I still don't see a question?

Comment: @Dominik edited again to hopefully provide more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Updated code

```js
const data = [
    { "coord": { "lon": 100.5167, "lat": 13.75 }, "weather": [{ "id": 802, "main": "Clouds", "description": "scattered clouds", "icon": "03n" }], "base": "stations", "main": { "temp": 28.96, "feels_like": 34.79, "temp_min": 28, "temp_max": 30.56, "pressure": 1011, "humidity": 83 }, "visibility": 10000, "wind": { "speed": 1.54, "deg": 200 }, "clouds": { "all": 40 }, "dt": 1614633761, "sys": { "type": 1, "id": 9235, "country": "TH", "sunrise": 1614641637, "sunset": 1614684397 }, "timezone": 25200, "id": 1609350, "name": "Bangkok", "cod": 200 },
    { "coord": { "lon": 150.7167, "lat": -30.75 }, "weather": [{ "id": 800, "main": "Clear", "description": "clear sky", "icon": "01d" }], "base": "stations", "main": { "temp": 18, "feels_like": 18.59, "temp_min": 18, "temp_max": 18, "pressure": 1011, "humidity": 94 }, "visibility": 10000, "wind": { "speed": 2.57, "deg": 150 }, "clouds": { "all": 0 }, "dt": 1614633937, "sys": { "type": 1, "id": 9604, "country": "AU", "sunrise": 1614628089, "sunset": 1614673852 }, "timezone": 39600, "id": 2158874, "name": "Manilla", "cod": 200 },
];
let html = [];

data.forEach(o => {
    html.push(`
<div class="forecast-card">
    <p class="date">Date: ${new Date()}</p>
    <p class="current-temp">Temp: ${o.main.temp} <sup>o</sup>C</p>
    <img src="./icons/${o.weather[0].icon}.png" alt="weather icons" class="icon">
    <p class="conditions">Conditions: ${o.weather[0].description}</p>
    <p class="high-temp">High temp ${o.main.temp_max} <sup>o</sup>C</p>
    <p class="low-temp">Low temp: ${o.main.temp_min} <sup>o</sup>C</p>
    <p class="humidity">Humidity: ${o.main.humidity}%</p>
</div>
<hr />`);
});

document.querySelector('.forecast-cards').innerHTML = html.join('');
```

```html
<div class="forecast-cards"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see you iterating over anything though?

Comment: This would likely work for one forecast card, but there are 5 objects within the array and therefore 5 forecast cards that I need to pull and fill data from. Hence trying to iterate over the array and grab each object.

Comment: You do a data.forEach for the data you want to loop throu

Comment: @BitAtWork yeah I got that much of it, but I don't understand what that should actually look like.

Comment: I've updated the example to contain 2 data sets

Comment: @Bardlock Now I want to make a weather app too